# What is the correct usage of C# var when using the interface members?

Tags: c#-4.0, var

Below is the interface and its implementation.

```
interface ICompanyService
{
    Company GetCompany();
}

public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
    public Company GetCompany()
    {
        //Do something
        return new Company();

    }
}
```

Now if below "companyService" is the implementation of above ICompanyService, which one is better (A or B) and why?

```
  var company = companyService.GetCompany(); //.....A

  Company company = companyService.GetCompany(); //.....B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Arnis says, they are identical underneath.
Personally I'd prefer B in this case since you can't see the return type just by looking at the statement.

Comment: That's what naming is for. Variable `company` seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: In the example this is true, but in general you could have the method returning an interface, or there could be multiple company classes; SmallCompany, LargeCompany or whaterver. Anyways, I prefer to use var only when I can see the return type (explicitly) by looking at the method.

Comment: If You have a need to know what's underneath interface - You are abusing them and doing it wrong

Comment: @Arnis Ok, an interface might have been a bad example. But what if the method returned a datarow f.ex.?

Comment: @Arnis, i don't think it is abusing. Code should be easier to read and easier to understand. This is probably not very good example, but generally, if the return type is not obvious, var is not a good choice in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical underneath.

`A` is better because of readability. But that's subjective. Some people like lengthy lines.

Comment: I thought B is more readable. For example GetCompany can return i.e ICompany. If we use var, it is not obvious.

Comment: @Joel I said, that's subjective. And interfaces shouldn't define structure but behavior.